# Working with CSS Grid and using each div as a button for a pop up modal and it is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here is an example of it not working.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKmv4l1WvLU&feature=youtu.be)We have a css grid set up to make each div a button for a pop up menu for each recipient. Iv'e inserted multiple codes and for some reason when I click on live it wont let me open the modal. When I place active on the button it shows up, so I know its there its just not appearing on click.

Also after this I might need to figure out how to keep each modal separate for each person. If anyone has a though of how I should go about this. It's greatly appreciated.

My knowledge with javascript is probably 20% or less. Please and thank you.

```js
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */

const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = button.closest('.modal')
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})

function openModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closeModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.sectionbk {
    background-color: #d7d2cb;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}
.midsection {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

h3 {
    color: #ff7477;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: bureau-grot, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

.parent { 
display: grid; 
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr); 
grid-column-gap: 50px;
grid-row-gap: 35px; 
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; } 
.div2 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; } 
.div3 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; } 
.div4 { grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4; } 
.div5 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2; } 
.div6 { grid-area: 4 / 2 / 5 / 3; } 
.div7 { grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4; } 
.div8 { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5; } 
.div9 { grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 6; } 
.div10 { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2; } 
.div11 { grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4; } 
.div12 { grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 5; } 
.div13 { grid-area: 6 / 2 / 7 / 3; } 
.div14 { grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4; } 
.div15 { grid-area: 7 / 3 / 8 / 4; } 
.div16 { grid-area: 8 / 2 / 9 / 3; } 
.div17 { grid-area: 8 / 3 / 9 / 4; } 
.div18 { grid-area: 8 / 4 / 9 / 5; } 
.div19 { grid-area: 9 / 3 / 10 / 4; } 
.div20 { grid-area: 9 / 4 / 10 / 5; } 
.div21 { grid-area: 10 / 3 / 11 / 4; } 

.static img{
    width: 100%;
    align-content: center;
}

.btn {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.modal.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header .title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}








.box-title{
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 60%;
}


.designers-sec{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 ;
    text-align: center;
}


img.student-single{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 100;
}

img.fun {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
}

.individual {
    position: relative;
}


button:hover img.fun  {
    display: block;
}

button:hover img.student-single {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/nya0twp.css">
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body class="sectionbk">
        <section class="midsection">
            <div class="parent" id=""> 
                
                    <div class="div1 static">
                            <button data-modal-target="#modal1" class="btn">    
                                <img class="student-single" src="PortfolioImagesgifs/Senior_ShowX06.png">
                                <img class="fun" src="PortfolioImagesgifs/Senior_ShowXGif.gif">
                                <div class="icon"></div>
                                <h3>Melissa Auburn</h3>   
                            </button>      
                    </div> 
                            
                <!---- Melissa Auburn ----------------------->
                
                
               <div class="modal" id="modal1">    
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <div class="modal-title">Stuff</div>
                            <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">nesciunt necessitatibus, consectetur quisquam accusamus ex, dolorum, dicta vel? Nostrum voluptatem totam, molestiae rem at ad autem dolor ex aperiam. Amet assumenda eos architecto
                            </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Can we have an example of when it's not working?

Comment: I updated the question with the youtube link so you can see it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not very helpful. There's obviously some kind of difference between the code here and the one that underlies example in your youtube video,  because this one here works and by the look of it, it should work, or at least I can't find any serious issues with it. Any logs in the console?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce behavior that  such youtube video. Do you reproduce it on code snippet too?

Comment: It's the same code but I'm noticing the code seems to work when I uploaded it into the prompt here, however the response I've recorded is when I'm working within Brackets. Do you think Brackets is the underlying issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I'm guessing it has some sort of live preview built-in? If so - yes, it might be a bug, or it just doesn't have some of the functionalities that a typical web browser have.